# Short way of inserting form data via Multiply select and Switcher in PHP Form to SQL table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

> I'm quite new in PHP and trying to make a website PHP/JS/MYSQL with
>   materialize.css framework on it.  I figured out by myself how to
>   perform crud operations but I got stacked at multiply choice selects
>   and switchers. I read a bit about it and it's mostly about ajax
>   requests but I wonder if there a way to do it without ajax or just
>   some short way around cause I haven't learned AJAX yet?  That's my code:

```
<!-- PHP Code for inserting stuff into table ------>
<?php
     require 'dbconnection.php';
     if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        //thats a normal name variable 
        $shortname = $_POST['shortname'];  
        //that's a variable for a multiply choice. 
        $worker = $_POST['worker'];
        //that's for a switcher. 
        $switcher = $_POST['switcher'];

         // validate input
         $valid = true;

         // inserting data
         if ($valid) {
             $pdo = Database::connect();
             $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
             $sql = "INSERT INTO tasks (shortname, worker, switcher) values(?, ?, ?)";
             $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
             $q->execute(array($shortname,$worker,$switcher));
             Database::disconnect();
             header("Location: index.php");
        }
     }
 ?>
```

> That's my html:

```
<li class="step active">
    <div class="step-title waves-effect">Step 1</div>
    <div class="step-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
                <label for="shortname">First Name: <span class="red-text">*</span></label>
                <!-- That's for "shortname" name input-->
                <input type="text" id="shortname" name="shortname" class="validate">
            </div>
            <div class="switch">
                <label>
                    Off
                    <!-- That's for "switcher" switcher-->
                    <input name="switcher" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="lever"></span> On
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field">
            <!-- That's for the multiply select "worker"-->
            <select name="worker" class="select2 browser-default" multiple="multiple">
                <optgroup label="Workers">
                    <option value="John">John</option>
                    <option value="Lara">Lara</option>
                    <option value="Lara">Corny</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

In PhpMYAdmin the table has such lines:

```
`shortname` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,  
`worker` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,  
`switcher` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8  NOT NULL,
```

Woud be thankful if you could help me to find a short way for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX is not essential (though you can do the same through...).

1. You can put your html code within

> ```
> <form name=myform method=post  action=yourprog>
> ```

and

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">    
</form>
```

2. Instead of form, you shall call a JS function through Submit button

> ```
> <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick= save_values();>
> ```

And in javascript section

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
 function save_values() {
  var tshortname= document.getElementById('shortname').value;
  var ...all the variables to be saved in database
  var tresult= HttpGet('yourprog.php?shortname=tshortname&v2=tv2&...');
  if(condition based on value of tresult)
   alert error
  else
   alert recorded
}
```

and for HttpGet please refer
[HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)